# Will a brief current generate if I connect with a conducting wire two pieces of elements with a large electronegativity difference?

Tags: electrons, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

I'm studying how voltaic cells behave and how batteries were invented.
I read this article on the [scientific american](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/degrees-of-freedom/the-periodic-table-and-batteries/), and it explains that if you connect a piece of zinc with a piece of copper  through a conducting wire, electrons starts to flow from the zinc to the copper ( for a short time).
This feels strange, I know that charges must travel only under the effect of an electric field, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. There are all sorts of weird effects that cause very small current flows.

Comment: Actually there is a field that vanishes because of that flow. Or if you prefer initially upon contact there is an electrical potential energy

Comment: Actually there is a field that vanishes because of that flow. Or if you prefer initially upon contact there is an electrical potential difference